# Server Deployed Asp.net button click error

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, server

I just recently published and deployed a website to a server. It will run the page requested. My issue is the minute I click a button it causes this error [my onClick method in the VB.net server back end is currently empty aka commented out code] and this is the error provided. I don't believe the `/>` is the `Server Error in '/' Application` cause.
[image]

I've added the HKEY requirements as well:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion
Add:
DWORD ForceLog set value to 1
DWORD LogFailures set value to 1
DWORD LogResourceBinds set value to 1
String LogPath set value to folder for logs (e.g. C:\FusionLog\)
```

I literally can't find out why every time I click a button this happens?
**This is on an IIS 7 server**

Comment: Did you check the installation of MySQL and related connection strings.

Comment: When I run the application from localhost connection and MySQL connects fine with button back end code. With the Server I checked that the same MySQL is installed as well. I verified I have folder read/write and etc permissions as well. @Baskar

Comment: `FileNotFound ... Could not load file or assembly MySql.Data` surely that means something to you?

Comment: If you are using nuget packages check if the required dlls are published to your application.

Comment: testing... i see my published host computer has a different version which tells me that when i publish it uses that... trying to reinstall the servers onto my computer right now